# Slicing based on interval multiplier

Tags: python, slice

I've the following values:

```
a = [33, 121, 230, 273, 303, 398, 445, 502, 613, 694, 721, 871, 935, 1045, 1021, 1079,
     1131, 1183]
```

I have a number 200. Based on this, I have to slice the value of a.
It's like `[200, 400, 600, ...]` — essentially multiples of 200.

I want to slice the value of `a` based on multiples of 200.

End result is list of lists below:

```
[33, 121]
[230, 273, 303, 398]
[445, 502]
[613, 694, 721]
[871, 935]
[1045, 1021, 1079, 1131, 1183]
```

Comment: That is not slicing. More of a condition based list copy. I'll try to provide a script as soon as possible.

Comment: thanks! I have the solution as iteration. But was looking for something simple using `zip()` function

Comment: What if one of the intervals has no values? Should the result include an empty list for it then or not?

Comment: 1079 comes before 1021. Is that a typo, or is the input not sorted? If it's not sorted, what output would you want if 121 and 230 were switched in your input?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. updated.

Comment: if it has no values, then we can exclude it. not necessary to show empty list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is

```py
cut = 200
intervals = [[k*cut, (k+1)*cut] for k in range(max(a)//cut + 1)]
[[itm for itm in a if itm > interval[0] and itm < interval[1]] for interval in intervals]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [itertools.groupby()](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group items in the list with key being `item//200`

```
from itertools import groupby

a = [33, 121, 230, 273, 303, 398, 445, 502, 613, 694, 721, 871, 935, 1045, 1079, 1021, 1131, 1183]
intervals = [list(g) for _, g in groupby(a, lambda x: x//200)]
```

Output -

```
[[33, 121], [230, 273, 303, 398], [445, 502], [613, 694, 721], [871, 935], [1045, 1079, 1021, 1131, 1183]]
```

Answer (score 1):

My implementation.

```
from math import ceil

a = [33, 121, 230, 273, 303, 398, 445, 502, 613, 694, 721, 871, 935, 1045, 1079, 1021, 1131, 1183]

num = 200
max_num = max(a)
divlist = [i*num for i in range(1,ceil(max_num/num)+1)]

dic = {}

for i in divlist:
    dic[i] = [x for x in a if (i-num)< x < i]

for i in divlist:
    print(dic[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution by creating ranges 0-200, 200-400 ...
And them determining if a number in the list `a` is in a given range

```
split_points = [i for i in range(0, max(a), 200)]
out: [0, 200, 400, 600, 800, 1000]

parts = [[number for number in a if number in range(split_point, split_point+200)] for split_point in split_points]

out:
[[33, 121],
 [230, 273, 303, 398],
 [445, 502],
 [613, 694, 721],
 [871, 935],
 [1045, 1079, 1021, 1131, 1183]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Though it is answered already, here is my solution

```
a = [33, 121, 230, 273, 303, 398, 445, 502, 613, 694, 721, 871, 935, 1045, 1079, 1021, 1131, 1183]
interval = 200
rang = range(0, max(a) + 1, interval)
b = enumerate(rang, start=1)
c = [list(filter(lambda n: (n < interval * i and n >= x), a)) for i,x in b]
```

Output:

```
[[33, 121], [230, 273, 303, 398], [445, 502], [613, 694, 721], [871, 935], [1045, 1079, 1021, 1131, 1183]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The filtering list comprehensions seem rather inefficient. You could directly compute the list that each value shall be appended to:

```
a = [33, 121, 230, 273, 303, 398, 445, 502, 613, 694, 721, 871, 935, 1045, 1021, 1079, 1131, 1183]
step = 200

result = [[] for _ in range(max(a) // step + 1)]
for x in a:
    result[x // step].append(x)

print(result)
```

Output;

```
[[33, 121], [230, 273, 303, 398], [445, 502], [613, 694, 721], [871, 935], [1045, 1021, 1079, 1131, 1183]]
```